# Keep getting 'Null' when pulling data from google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Whenever I try to pull data from 2 of 3 sheets from using the 'google.script.run' function call from Javascript, I keep getting an error saying the array I am returning is Null, but when I just change the exact same function call to work on another sheet, it returns the data perfectly

I have tried deleting the sheets and giving it the same names, I have tried using 'openWithURL' instead of 'getActive' to access the spreadsheet, I have tried rewriting the code, I have tried the same code in a different project, and checking the documentation to make sure I am not missing any detail. I have tried changing the references to the sheets, some work and some dont.

```
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

var DB_BOOKINGS = SS.getSheetByName("BookingDatabase");
var DB_VEHICLES = SS.getSheetByName("VehicleDatabase");
var DB_REQUESTS = SS.getSheetByName("RequestDatabase");

function getRequestData(){

 return DB_REQUESTS.getDataRange().getValues(); 
}

<script>
      function getRequestData(callingFunction) {
         google.script.run
         .withSuccessHandler(callingFunction)
         .withFailureHandler(CustomAlert)
         .getRequestData();

        }
</script>
```

I want to retrieve the sheet data but keep getting a null value

Comment: Really not sure what you're trying to do here - is your last function part of your HTML?

Comment: yes sorry mate, the last part is the function call I am making to the sheets in my HTML. funnily enough, I just tried pasting other data from the sheet that works into the sheet that doesn't and it worked for a few minutes...still haven't found the root cause

Comment: I have found the cause, formatting columns with dates or times in them causes the script to return a null, keeping them in their plain values allows things to work! No idea why this is?

Comment: That's strange - out of interest could you try using `.getDisplayValues()` with the formatting and see if it returns anything?

Comment: yes that seems to have worked perfectly, I formatted the dates and times aget and used .getDisplayValues() and it's working fine now, thank you very much buddy. Any idea why this even happened? I haven't had this experience before. Also how do I mark you comment as the correct answer?

Comment: You can't - I'll add it as an answer instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is an issue with formatting as you said, try using `getDisplayValues()` rather than `getValues()`, this will pull the data as you see it in the sheet (as a string), rather than the unformatted data itself.

---

#### Reference:

- [`getDisplayValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValues())

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. This was exactly the solution I needed. For my situation, I was able to use `getValues()` successfully on the initial page load, but when I tried to run it again as a sort of 'refresh' to update the values without reloading the entire page, it would return `null`.
My data did indeed contain dates, so after changing it to `getDisplayValues()`, it worked perfectly.