# HTML loads and fire function before apps script return value

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have a server side code.

then client side javascript and a html page made using bootstrap.

The problem I am facing is somehow document is loading before the server side returns value.

here is my server side code

> Edit: you must mean client side here

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fetchdata).datafetch();
   
  });

function fetchdata(dataArray)
  
  {
  let tbody = document.getElementById('perf1');
  
  for (var i=0; i<dataArray.length;i++)
  {
    
    var row = document.createElement("tr")
    row.setAttribute("style","height:2px;")
    for (var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++)
     {
           var col = document.createElement("td")
           
           if (j==0)
           {
           col.innerText = dataArray[i][j]
           }
    row.appendChild(col)
     }
     tbody.appendChild(row);
  }
}
```

here is server side code :

```
function datafetch()
{
   
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxx');
  var sheet = ss2.getSheetByName('Video');
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  email = email.replace(/@gmail.com/g, "")
  var lrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var a = sheet.getRange("A1:A"+lrow).getValues();
  a=a.filter(String)
  
  var data = sheet.getRange("A2:R"+a.length).getValues();
  
  var data1 = data.filter(function(item){return item[9] == email}).map(elem => elem[0]);
  data1.flat();
  
  Logger.log(data1)
  
  return data1;
}
```

I am trying to load a table from the data that I fetched from google sheet but it returns empty array. On server side I am able to see the log and array has values. but on client side it shows null.

Comment: You can use the JavaScript fetch API to get data from the server and then run the `withSuccessHandler` method on the returned data.

Comment: is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: "somehow document is loading before the server side returns value" - why would your code do anything else?

Comment: @goldenbanana42 that's not what he asked

Comment: @Cooper I'm just trying to understand what he expected would happen.

Comment: I have edited my question above. what I am trying to achieve is to get the server-side values and create a table body. But the script from client side returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Findings

On my testing, your current code structure below should work as it will first load the HTML file before fetching the array data from your spreadsheet:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fetchdata).datafetch();
});

function fetchdata(dataArray) {
//code
}
```

- The `null` result is most likely due to the `getValues()` method that you're using on your server side code that contains date/time. You should use [`getDisplayValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) instead & adjust your server side code accordingly. See this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56683559/15384825) answer.

> ***Note:*** Correct me if I'm mistaken about you do not have any time/date values on your sheet that you're fetching. Then, you can share your sheet file with sample actual data to better replicate your issue.

### Testing

1.) **Tested this client side code below & used `alert(dataArray)` method to quickly see if array data gets fetched/shown successfully**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fetchdata).datafetch();

});

function fetchdata(dataArray) {

alert(dataArray);

}
```

2.) **Used the `getDisplayValues()` on server side code:**

```
function datafetch(){
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Data').getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  Logger.log(values);
  return values;
}
```

3.) **Test Sheet "Data" used:**

[image]

### Test Results

> **When using getDisplayValues() on server side, it returns the actual array values**

[image]

> **When using getValues() on server side, it returns *null***

[image]

Comment: Looks like you know the exact reason. Great job helping out.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't run during evaluate:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fetchdata).datafetch();
  });

function fetchdata(dataArray) {
  alert(dataArray)
}
```

The above process run after the document is loaded so yes the HTML loads before datafetch() is even called

Comment: But how would the OP modify the code to give the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You could always try this:

```
<script>
  function ready() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fetchdata).datafetch();
  }
  function fetchdata(dataArray) {
    alert(dataArray)
  }
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
</script>
```